# Convert Form Group data to a class in Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form group that is being passed into the component as input parameter and I need to pass that to a method as an object of the class. Is there a easy way to convert the form group which contains the form control into a class

Class

```
export class CustomerClass{
  custNo?: string;
  CustName?: string;
  CustAddress: string;
}
```

FormGroup

```
    const group: FormGroup = this._fb.group({
      CustAddress: this._fb.control('test'),
      custNo: this._fb.control(''),
      CustAddress: this._fb.control(''),
    });
```

Component

```
  @Input()
  CustomerGroup: FormGroup;

//Now I need this as a object of class to pass it to a function

submit() {
this.customerservice.processCustomer(CustomerGroup);

}
```

Service

```
processCustomer(customer: CustomerClass){
//do stuff
}
```

Can I easily convert the form group to a class? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try by getting the value from the form ? It will returns an object with the class properties.

```
    this.customerservice.processCustomer(this.myForm.value);

//in your case if you want to send the form object that you are getting in the input.

    this.customerservice.processCustomer(this.CustomerGroup?.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class only has properties (not method) use [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). If you use interface you can "cast" simply using:

```
this.customerservice.processCustomer(this.CustomerGroup.value as CustomerInterface);
```

Else you need create an object of the class CustomerClass and pass:

```
const customer=new CustomerClass();
customer.custNo=this.CustomerGroup.value.custNo;
...
this.customerservice.processCustomer(customer);
```